# command libtool failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am following exact steps to configure firebase in an iOS application but I am having "command libtool failed with a nonzero exit code firebase" error while building the project. I have tried clean and build and it is not working. Any idea how to fix this?